# Hidden values PHP

Tags: php, post

```
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;">Mobiltelefon</td>
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;"><?=number_format($mobil);?> kr</td>
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;"><form method="POST"><input type="text" size="4" name="amountm"><input type="hidden" name="special" value="$mobil"></td>
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;"><input type=submit name=selgmob value="Selg"></td>
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" name="special" value="PHONE"><input type=submit name=buymob value="Kjøp"></form></td>
```

There is my code ,  but in the last line it is like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="special" value="PHONE">
```

After pressing the button, and using

```
      $ting = $_post['special'];


        echo "the special is : $ting ";
```

In this code, it is not echoing out my hidden form, ( PHONE), that i would like it to do.
right now its echoing out: "the special is  :  "

What is wrong with my code, (and  is it possible to improve this?)?

everything works except the hidden value.

Comment: Use `$_POST` and not `$_post`

Comment: If you want to be W3C valid, always use quotes when defining the value of an attribute: `<tag attribute="value">`. It may be a typo, but you wrote `<input type=submit name=buymob value="Kjøp">`

Comment: Check your HTML. You can't have `<td><form></td><td></form></td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to access post values is to use the predefined variable `$_POST` (all capitals). I would also consider using the `htmlentities` function to sanitise the incoming data before you display it on your web page.

Also, unless you are going to use the variable `$ting` again later, you can cut out the middle-man.

```
echo "the special is : ".htmlentities($_POST['special']);
```

#### More Info

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 3):

It's $_POST not $_post, it's case-sensitive.

Comment: thank you, I feel really stupid that completely forgot that it is case-sensitive

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
$ting = $_POST['special'];
echo "the special is : ".$ting;
```

It will be the `$_POST`.Not `$_post`.

Comment: Sorry I wrote but while copy paste first line has missed

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
$ting = $_post['special']; as  $ting = $_POST['special'];
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
 <form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="special" value="PHONE">
  <input type="submit" name="buymob" value="Kjøp">
 </form>
```

**php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['special']))
{
   $ting = $_POST['special'];
   echo "the special is : $ting "; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code, you have that:

```
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;">Mobiltelefon</td>
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;"><?=number_format($mobil);?> kr</td>
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;">
   <form method="POST">
     <input type="text" size="4" name="amountm">
     <input type="hidden" name="special" value="$mobil">
</td>
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;">
     <input type=submit name=selgmob value="Selg">
</td>
<td class=mainTxt style="text-align: center;">
     <input type="hidden" name="special" value="PHONE">
     <input type=submit name=buymob value="Kjøp">
   </form>
</td>
```

Firstly, you have two "special" inputs, then PHP interpret the first "special" input, after that, the correct PHP code is:

```
$ting = $_POST['special'];
echo "the special is : $ting ";
```

Because POST is a PHP keyword, if you don't type the correct keyword, PHP interpret it as simple variable name, in your case, PHP interpreted the value 'special' of the $_post array defined by the programmer, it's different to the $_POST.

I hope this has been helpful.

Good lucky my friend =D